# Overloading arguments of inherited types

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading

Alright so I just want to confirm something.

I am creating a wrapper class for java's Properties class and I came a cross a little question.

if I have

```
public static void set(String key, Object value) { _p.set(key, value.toString()); }
```

and

```
public static void set(String key, SomeClass value) { _p.set(key, value.SomeMethod().toString()); }
```

is the `Object` overload called only when none of the other overloads suffice?

Comment: `boolean` does not derive from `Object`, since it is a [primitive](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: I know what a primitive is. Could have just as easily been `Boolean`.

Comment: 6.5 years later and my comment above was completely bitchy. Sorry. (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java will choose the most specific match, in your case a boolean will be automatically converted using auto-boxing boolean <-> Boolean. If you use any other type like String the Object variant will be used.

The Details you find in the [Java Language
Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf)
see 8.4.9 Overloading

Added in response to comment:

You can easily test the behaviour with some code like:

```
class A {
    public void print(Object o) {
        System.out.println("A.print " + o);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        A a = new A();
        b.print("test b");
        a.print("test a");
        ((A) b).print("test a or b");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void print(Object o) {
        System.out.println("B.print " + o);
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
B.print test b
A.print test a
B.print test a or b
```

I hope now it is more clear what happens.

Comment: Java will choose the *most specific* match.

Comment: @Di-0xide That's not what I said, and it's not correct. What I said is correct. See the JLS. You won't find waffle like 'latest applicable derivative' in there.

Comment: So for example if there were two classes `A` and `B`, where `B` extended `A`, and I had a method that was overloaded with one parameter of types `Object`, `A`, and `B`. Which is called when I call it with an object of type `A`? Which is called when I call with type `B`? Which is called when I call it with a type `C` that extends `A`?

Comment: @di-0xide I added a short example.

Comment: Your example is not overloading, it is overriding

Answer (score 4):

This is a very dangerous pattern to use and is actually advised against explicitly in Effective Java. The problem is that the method signature resolution happens statically, at compile time, so it doesn't depend on the actual type of arguments at runtime, only their declared type.

Comment: I figured as much. I had changed it to specific types (no `Object` types) before I even asked the question, but the question was still on my mind.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the *type of the reference* you pass to this method. E.g.

```
Objeyt myObject = Boolean.TRUE;
YourClass.set("foo", myObject);
```

will *not* invoke the method with the Boolean in its parameter list. It will choose the `Object` version.

See e.g. the constructor for `java.util.TreeSet(Collection c)` in your jdk. Similar stuff is going on there as well (it checks if the collection is actually a `SortedSet`, but there *is* a constructor for `SortedSet`).

Try

```
public class A {

    public void method(String str) {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }

    public void method(Object obj) {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        Object obj = "A String";
        a.method(obj);
    }

}
```

This prints *bar*. Strange but true :)

Comment: this is not strange, but absolutely expected IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Posting the following example:

```
public class Inherit {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, Inheritance!");

    Parent parent = new Parent();
    Parent childp = new Child();
    Child childc = new Child();

    System.out.println("===============================");
    parent.print(parent);
    parent.print(childp);
    parent.print(childc);

    System.out.println("===============================");
    childp.print(parent);
    childp.print(childp);
    childp.print(childc);

    System.out.println("===============================");
    childc.print(parent);
    childc.print(childp);
    childc.print(childc);

  }

}

class Parent {
    public void print(Parent x) {
       System.out.println("Parent.print(Parent)");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    public void print(Child x) {
       System.out.println("Child.print(Child)");
    }

    @Override
    public void print(Parent x) {
       System.out.println("Child.print(Parent)");
    }
}
```

and the output

```
Hello, Inheritance!
===============================
Parent.print(Parent)
Parent.print(Parent)
Parent.print(Parent)
===============================
Child.print(Parent)
Child.print(Parent)
Child.print(Parent)
===============================
Child.print(Parent)
Child.print(Parent)
Child.print(Child)
```